# PowerShell: Give user permission to connect to database engine

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
Import-Module SqlServer

$compName = $env:computername
$username = "user"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “TestPassword123” -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance $compName"\SQLSERVER" -LoginType "SqlLogin" -DefaultDatabase "master" -LoginPSCredential $cred -Enable

$sql = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]::new($compName+"\SQLSERVER")
$sql.Settings.LoginMode = 'Mixed'
$sql.Alter()
Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLSERVER' | Restart-Service
```

The purpose of this script is to change the authentication mode from `Windows Authentication mode` to `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode` and create a user that can log in and access the `master` database.

When I run this script, the authentication mode is change and the user is created but under `Permission to connect to database engine` the setting is set to `Deny` which is preventing the user to log in. Also, the passoword specified in the script isn't the same password being applied to the user in the database (if  I change the password of the user in SSMS to the password in the script and set `Permission to connect to database engine` to `Grant` then the user can log in).

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. How can I create a user, specifiy a password and allow that user to log in and to connect to the database via PowerShell?